# Inserting digraphs but unintentionally holding down CTRL key

Tags: gvim, digraphs

In insert mode, I insert digraphs using `CTRL-k`. For example, I get `é` by pressing `CTRL-k ' e`.

However, when typing fast, I am often still holding down the CTRL key when I hit the `'` key which cause Vim to insert `<C-'>` into the document.

How can I stop Vim from doing this?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I have this problem a lot, too, but the only solution I have found so far is to improve my typing and not hold control :)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. :) Still, I'm optimistic that there must be a solution. The insertion of these <C-'> seems like a "feature" rather than some fundamental behavior. Surely we can turn this feature off!

Comment: Pressing `<C-k><C-'>e` in insert mode actually inserts the expected `é` for me; this is because my terminal just sends `'` for `<C-'>`; which terminal are you using?

Comment: Interesting: In text-mode Vim I get the desired é as you do. It looks like it is only in Gvim where the <C-k><C-'> immediately inserts a <C-'>. My shell is zsh.

Comment: Oh yeah, keyboard input for gvim works a bit different (and you *can* use `<C-'>` there).

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the last comment. I guess my question is: How can I stop GVIM from inserting the text <C-'> when I type <C-k><C-'> in insert mode.

Comment: Have you tried the naive "fix": `:inoremap <C-k><C-'>e é`. Does it work? (I can't reproduce your exact issue here, so I can't test.) Is setting up such mappings for the most common of your typoes remotely feasible, or are there too many of them?

Comment: @Rich's suggestion seems to fix my specific problem -- thanks! I've also thrown in a :inoremap <C-k><C-'><C-e> é to cover all the bases. It would still be nice to understand why GVIM inserts text like "<C-'>" and how that can be turned off in general.

Comment: It can't be "turned off."  Apps use libraries to capture keyboard input.  It happens to be that TUI libs consider `<C-'>` to be `'`, because of historical reasons. GUI libs are more recent, and they are more robust and consider `<C-'>` to be what it is.  Vim can't turn off the library implementation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a clean solution, but a common workaround is to remap your most common typos to do what you want. e.g.

```
:inoremap <C-k><C-'>e é
```

Comment: There is also the `:digraph` command to add digraphs

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Though I wonder how you'd enter the `<C-'>` in the command, I'm guessing this might work `:execute "digraph \<C-'>e é"` but then I don't reproduce the original problem so I don't know how I'd test that...

Comment: Why not use `: if gvim | inoremap <c-k><c-'> <c-k>' | endif`?